# Check Space for a child view before adding to root view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

How can i check space for a **child view**

For example my child view regenerate a number b/w 1 to 40

```
LinearLayout root=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearroot);

        for(int i=1;i<40;i++)
        {
            TextView aa=new TextView(this);
            aa.setText(""+i);
            root.addView(aa);
        }
```

while adding a sub child to root  view. If it reach to the bottom of screen then it should create a child view to right side like this

```
1 10 | 19
2 11 | 20
3 12 | 21
4 13 | 22
5 14 | 23  <-> 19-27 hidden, but columns scrollable horizontally
6 15 | 24
7 16 | 25
8 17 | 26
9 18 | 27
```

Can any one know about the space calculation.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: get the height in pixel and get you view height compare them if exceed shift